# php not logging into mysql or responding

Tags: php, mysql, http, mysqli, amazon-ec2

I have a php script I wrote and it will not return anything except "Hello".

```
<?php

echo "Hello";

$username = "me";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbname";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

echo "logged in";

// Sanitize variable
$user_id = intval($_GET['user_id']);

//update likes on specific id
$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT user_score FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'")
  or die("Unable to query");

// Send back the score
$return = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $return[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($return);

//close the connection
mysqli_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

I had this script working before, then I moved it to another instance. I know I can login with my credentials to mysql and check that I have all privileges, and I know my username and password are correct. Is there something I need to change in my php? Or is there something I need to do so that when I access through a browser it shows like turn on the server?

I am not having anything returned except Hello, it does not even tell me "Unable to connect". This is very confusing to me. I should at least see "logged in" OR "Unable to connect" right?

Comment: remove the die statement after the connection string and replace it with this. Then see if you are getting an error.
if (!$dbhandle)
  {
  die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

Comment: In addition to the above, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I tried both of these, neither work. The "Hello" actually disappears now.

Comment: I tested your code and got this back `Hellologged in[{"user_score":"500"}]` so, check your column names, DB selection etc. The `500` is what I entered in the column and id is `1`.

Comment: Instead of `die()`, replace with `$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname); if($dbhandle->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $dbhandle->connect_error . ']');
}` - Your code should work.

Comment: Plus, how are you using this? I take it that you're using either an `href` with a GET method. Show us how you're using it. My test consisted of adding `$_GET['user_id'] = 1;` on top `$user_id = intval($_GET['user_id']);` in order to have a match, instead of setting a form etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help fred -ii-. Now I am showing this error "Class 'mysqli' not found in test.php on line 8" is this a problem with my version of php or mysql? I am using an amazon ec2

Comment: You're welcome. Which version of PHP are you using, are you using this on local machine or hosted website? As for Amazon, I couldn't help you in that area. If on own machine, is PHP installed? Is MySQL installed? etc.

Comment: I am on a remote instance of Amazon EC2, I need to look into getting it to work, thanks for your help

Comment: Ok well, I can't help you there. See if KillaBilla's method suggestion below will work for you then.

Comment: See this Q&A http://serverfault.com/questions/512264/connecting-to-a-new-rds-instance-from-an-ec2-instance there might be something in there that is related to your problem and also http://serverfault.com/questions/314686/remote-server-cant-access-rds-database - These findings after Googling `"remote instance of Amazon EC2 mysqli not working"` if you wish to further your research. And/or post your question on http://serverfault.com/ - I also added the relevant tag (`Amazon EC2`) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your are mixing the object oriented and procedural mysqli functions. When using the mysqli-constructor an object is returned even on failure, therefore the error is never shown.

Use this code instead to connect to your database:

```
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("mysqli_connect failed");
```

Check the [mysqli-documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) for further information.

Comment: The documentation doesn't contain `or die("mysqli_connect failed")` - It contains `if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}`

Comment: The difference between your answer and the OP, are the messages inside `die()`. Yours `or die("mysqli_connect failed")` OP's `or die("Unable to connect to MySQL")`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because the other functions were all written in procedural style I used the procedural connect-method. When using the OO style constructor your are right. I am referring to the last example code which says `$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}`. The 'or' basically means `if(!thingLeftHandside)`.

Comment: Ah ok. I noticed what you meant now. Ok well we will wait if OP has tried it then.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't getting any output because of your error_reporting settings in PHP.  The first step would be to set `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini`, along with `error_reporting = E_ALL`.  This will show all errors and you will get more information from your code snippet above.  You can also set the error_reporting level in the PHP file itself by adding this line at the top of your file: `error_reporting(-1);`

More info on error_reporting [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: You can also use `ini_set('display_errors', true);` in your script, for anyone who doesn't have access to php.ini :)